# Which sententiae are de Fide but are not defined by a Pope or an Ecumenical Council

Tags: catholicism, systematic-theology, dogma

*De Fide* is the highest [Theological Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogma_in_the_Catholic_Church#Theological_certainties) used by the Catholic theologians prior to the mid-20th Century. Of the sentences proposed for belief, there is that which comes directly from God (*de Fide Divina*) and that which comes from the Church (*de Fide Ecclesiastica*) and if a truth has been infallibly defined by a Pope or Ecumenical Council, it is *de Fide Definita*.

[traditionalcatholic.net](http://traditionalcatholic.net/Tradition/Information/Dogmas_of_the_Church.html) lists All the *sententiae* that Ludwig Ott labels *De Fide*.

My question is: **Which of those dogmas are NOT infallibly defined?**